# Is $\{A\}\subseteq B$ ⟺ $A\in B$ in Set Theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am learning Set Theory using the book "Axioms and Set Theory" by Robert André, and it asks me to prove the following exercise:

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets, show that $P(A) \in P(B)$ implies $P(A) \subseteq B$, and so $A \in B$.

And for it, I thought it could help me to know if my assumption is true.

$$\{A\} \subseteq B⟺A \in B.$$

I thought so because by the book's definition $A\subseteq B$ means "All elements of $A$ are elements of $B$" and $A\in B$ means "$A$ is an element of $B$". And I thought the element of $\{A\}$ is $A$, so it could be right.

I am not a mathematician or in University. Thank you for reading it.

Comment: Have you tried checking the definition of $\subseteq$ and $\{A\}$?

Comment: I presume by $\{A\} \subseteq B = A \in B$ you mean the statements $\{A\} \subseteq B$ and $A \in B$ are equivalent; that is, one holds if and only if the other one holds.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. No, I was a little dumb, sorry.

Comment: @GabrielSilvaSchilive You're not dumb. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question!  You wrote "Is $\{A\} \subseteq B  = A \in B$?"

A better (at least, more standard) way to write your question is:

Is $\{A \} \subseteq B \iff A \in B$ true?

In math, we tend to save the $=$ symbol for algebraic expressions (like, $x = 2$, or $2x + 1 = y$, etc.).  Your question is asking if the statement "$\{A \} \subseteq B$" is **equivalent** to the statement "$A \in B$".  So instead of the middle $=$ symbol, you should use the $\iff$ symbol.

The answer is yes.  Let's look at the definition of the symbol $\subseteq$.

Suppose $C$ and $D$ are two sets.  We say $C \subseteq D$ if every element of $C$ is in $D$, i.e., for each $c \in C$, we have $c \in D$.

Your first statement says $\{A \} \subseteq B$.  By the definition above, every element of the set $\{A \}$ must be in $B$.  But the set $\{A\}$ has only one element: $A$.  So if $\{A\} \subseteq B$, we have $A \in B$.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 2):

Yes: saying that $\{A\}\subseteq B$ is the same as $A\in B$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you something about assumptions? How far can I go with it in mathematics or it does not work like that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "assumption". In usual set theory, this is a theorem.

Comment: @GabrielSilvaSchilive In mathematics, we work with assumptions all of the time.  Most mathematical statements (e.g., theorems) have the form: "If assumption A1 is true, and assumption A2 is true, then Y holds."  It is our job as mathematicians to find the most general assumptions we can where $Y$ still holds.

Comment: @Gae.S. I will start to write down the most important definitions and theorems to remember.